# GPIO9 Input Always Active

Tags: gpio, pi-4, python-3, spi, input-device

Porting an application from a RPi 3 to an RPi 4 that requires several button inputs. All are working properly, except the button in [GPIO9 (Pin 21)](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin21_gpio9) is always high/true. Guessing this has to do with SPI interface and Pin 21 defaulting to high, but can't figure out how to get around it. Any direction would be fantastic.

#### Simplified application

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

buttonPin = 9

GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

try:
    while 1:
        button = GPIO.input(buttonPin)

        if button == True:
            sys.stdout.write("Button Pressed")

        sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)
```

#### Environment

- RPi 4
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Python 3.9.2
- SPI interface is not enabled in `raspi-config`

#### Outcome

This application returns "Button" regardless of button state:

- Button pressed or not
- Hardware (same result with other hardware)
- Connection (returns `True` even if nothing is connected!)

#### Troubleshooting

- Different hardware (as above)
- Application returns expected results for several other GPIO inputs, including [GPIO10 (PIN19)](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin19_gpio10), which is SPI0 MOSI

Comment: `can't figure out how to get around it` ... use a different pin ... what is your specific question?

Comment: GPIO 9  should be available.  What does `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs mg 9` report?

Comment: @jsotola - True, but it's far more convenient to use this pin. `What is your specific question`: What is the cause of this behavior? How do I make this pin work as intended?
@joan - `pigs mg 9` returns `0`

Comment: That leaves faulty GPIO or faulty wiring.

Comment: To check for faulty GPIO try https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing